# Загрузка библиотек вручную

Tags: android, library, android-gradle, loading

Появился очень интересный вопрос (как и прошлый про апк), можно ли как-то загрузить jar-файл библиотеки, имея только его gradle (eg. "com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:+"). Сразу скажу, что можно, есть такая реализация в андроид-компиляторах, мне хотелось бы узнать как именно это делать, и так же с андроида.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, как конкретно это делают системы сборки и т.д., но вполне может прокатить такой вариант — если вы будете собирать всё вручную, то вы будете знать, какие репозитории доступны у проекта. Для одного репозитория — maven central — всё довольно просто, наверняка у остальных система такая же.

Пути до файлов выглядят примерно так:

```
http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp/okhttp/2.7.5/
```

Соответственно, не так трудно догадаться, как эту ссылку получить из `com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5`. То есть ссылки до jar-ников вполне можно формировать вручную.

Оттуда уже вытаскиваете конкретный файл, который тоже будет назван «по маске»:

```
okhttp-2.7.5.jar
```

Comment: Это почти то, что мне нужно. Очень благодарен Вам, сам бы не нашел.

Comment: А возможно ли как-нибудь получить самую новую версию ? Например OkHttp:+

Comment: @SokolSokolinskiy делайте обычный `GET`-запрос, парсите страничку.